# Type conversion from string to User defined type

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I have a string type to be assigned to owner of type '`User`'. My method `GetFullName` returns the name in a '`string`' format and i need to assign it to owner of type '`User`'

```
def.Owner = uf.GetFullName(row["assignedto"].ToString());
```

Any suggestions would be helpful,

Comment: Why not simply do something like `def.Owner = new User(yourstring);`?

Comment: as of now i do not have a constructor for User class. It has been coded by someone else, So creating a constructor is the only way to do this?

Comment: If you can assign a new value to the `User`'s `FullName` attribute, you can simply instantiate a new `User` with whatever constructor you have, set the name from `row["assignedto"]` and then set the `Owner` to this newly created `User` instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you need something like:

```
public class User
{
    ...

    public static implicit operator User(string x)
    {
        return new User(x);
    }
}
```

Personally, I'm not a fan of implicit conversions, however. You say that you "need" to assign it this way... what's wrong with an explicit constructor or static method call? Or *perhaps* an extension method (`ToUser`) on `string`?

Comment: so do i need to create a constructor for User class ?

Answer (score 1):

@Jon's answer will do what you want, but you may want to look into the [repository pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) for managing the creation of domain objects.  That'll solve the bigger problem of making sure the code that uses the domain objects doesn't become wrapped around the axle just managing their lifetimes and serialization/deserialization.  Let the repository take care of such concerns and focus on your domain logic.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution with conversion operator, however, I'd personally prefer a static class method like User.FromString(string s) that parses the string and constructs a User instance. This way the code with be more readable and much easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

You can overload the explicit/implicit operators.
Take a look [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0160__Operator-Overload/explicitimplicitoperatorforComplex.htm)